# How can I use a different ToString method in a derived class?

Tags: c#, tostring

I have a List of CARS and I display the list in a Listbox using an overridded ToString method. 
I have derived classes for models of cars(eg hatchback), I need to display more information about the derived car models without loosing the base tostring method.

How can I display the CARS list in one listbox and the "hatchback" details in a different listbox.

If I override the ToString in the Models class it overrides the details I'm trying to display for CARS also.

Thanks
Sorry, C#
My Cars method is

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + " [" + this.GetType().Name.ToString() + "] called " + Type;
    }
```

But when I create a derived class I sometimes want to use the ToString from the derived class and not always the one from the base class.

Comment: Can you tag this with the respective language and post the code you've tried?

Comment: "sometimes" when?  Under what conditions?

Comment: can you not just call base.ToString in the derived classes and put the logic in the derived implementation code?

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that you can't do what you've described.  Once you've overridden a virtual method in a derived class you cannot access the version in the base class from the derived class.

I would consider adding a new method or property to the derived class for retrieving hatchback-specific information.

```
class Car
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "some basic info"; // Whatever you want
    }
}

class Hatchback : Car
{
     public string HatchbackInfo
     {
         get{return "some hatchback info";}  // Return some details only hatchbacks have
     }
}
```

When consuming a collection of Car objects that could actually be hatchbacks you can check the type of the object and act accordingly:

```
public void DoSomeStuffWithCars(List<Car> cars)
{
      foreach(Car c in cars)
      {
          Hatchback h = c as Hatchback.
          if(h != null)  // alternatively you can use the 'is' operator
          {
               // do some hatchback stuff with h.HatchbackInfo
          } 
          // logic here applies to all cars
      }
}
```

Comment: -1 Behaviour which varies according to which derived type the object is should be in virtual methods.

Comment: @ClickRick:  The OP didn't ask for a behavior that varied according to derived type.  They asked for a way to associate information specifically with a derived type only.